# What causes a Visual Studio project to sport a "10"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I've been wrestling with a humongous solution (over 30 projects*). Yesterday improvement was seen when a new local location was set up, and the TFS bindings mapped differently. Now I see when I open Visual Studio (2010) that the two entries in the "Recent Projects" list are both the same project, but the more recent one (the one with the new TFS mappings) has a "10" in the NE corner of the form/VS icon.

What does this decoration indicate?

- Someone will probably pipe up/weigh in with a, "That's nothing - my solution has 42,000 projects!"

Comment: Overlay icon perhaps?

Comment: Right, but why? Is it because the second project is no longer "there"? If so, it would seem it would overlay a "red circle with a diagonal cross through it" (whatever that image is called).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you double click a .txt file, Notepad launches. When you double click a .docx file, Word launches. And when you double click a .sln - it's complicated. Usually what will launch is a little helper app that looks in the .sln to figure out whether to launch VS 2008, VS 2012, or whatever.

The overlay indicates a VS version number - not a year. For VS 2012 solutions, it looks like this:

[image: vs 11 logo]

VS 10 is 2010; VS 9 is 2008. A lack of a version number overlay means the little helper hasn't figured out which version this is for.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, as the link is similar to some of the steps at the Winchester Mystery House, and leads nowhere.